# Angular - send checked state from child to parent component

Tags: angular

I have a checkbox in a child component. I want to emit it's state to the parent component. What do I do in the parent component after I have set up this event emitter in the child?

Child template:

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="isChecked" (change)="checkValue($event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

Child TS:

```
  @Output() onChecked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public checkValue(isChecked: any): void {
    this.onChecked.emit(isChecked);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did the hard part. After that you just need to listen to the output.

*parent.component.html*

```
<app-child (onChecked)="childOnChecked($event)"></app-child>
```

*parent.component.ts*

```
childOnChecked(isChecked: boolean) {
  // here your logic
}
```